# Emulate the Professor's typing

Tags: code-golf, keyboard

## Emulate the Professor's typing

**Background**

Unfortunately, the Professor is not able to use his keyboard properly: whenever he is meant to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, he presses <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> **once** before typing, and doesn't bother to correct himself. If there are two or more keys in a row that require <kbd>Shift</kbd>, he presses <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> before the first one and does nothing before the others.

As his secretary, I want to replicate this effect so that people think that he is the one replying to his emails, not me. He knows his typing looks stupid, but he doesn't care.

**Task**

Write a program that takes STDIN or file input of some text, and then outputs that text as if it had been typed by the Professor.

This is **code golf**, and standard loopholes are not allowed.

**Keyboard layout**

```
Default:
` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - =
   q w e r t y u i o p [ ]
    a s d f g h j k l ; ' #
   \ z x c v b n m , . /

With shift:
¬ ! " £ $ % ^ & * ( ) _ +
   Q W E R T Y U I O P { }
    A S D F G H J K L : @ ~
   | Z X C V B N M < > ?

With caps lock:
` 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 - =
   Q W E R T Y U I O P [ ]
    A S D F G H J K L ; ' #
   \ Z X C V B N M , . /
```

**Example input / output**

(The `CapsLock` line is just there for your understanding, and should not be outputted in your program)

```
Input:    abc ** def ! (ghijkl) mnop
Output:   abc 88 DEF 1 9GHIJKL0 mnop
CapsLock:     *      * *      *       (* means Caps Lock was pressed before this character)

Input:    print("Hello, World!"); sys.exit()
Output:   print92HELLO, world120; SYS.EXIT90
CapsLock:      *        *    *            *

Input:    !ABC!abc!ABC!abc!x!y!z
Output:   1ABC1ABC1abc1abc1X1y1Z
CapsLock: *       *       * * *
```

Comment: I would say that the opposite of this task would be more interesting :) (i.e to correct his wrongly types mails)

Comment: @Optimizer Too ambiguous. Input `HELLO` could be "corrected" to `Hello`, `HEllo`, `HELlo`, etc.

Comment: But the correct would be `Hello` only, as defined by word case (or fixed rules of correct English casing)

Comment: @Optimizer Sure, just pointing out it would need some strict rules, especially regarding numbers/symbols, which could be way more ambiguous than standard prose text. I agree it would be fun if done right.

Comment: @Geobits Perhaps that could be a bonus (e.g. 50% bytes)?

Comment: @laurencevs Honestly I'd rather see it as a separate challenge :)

Comment: What kind of voodoo keyboard is this?

Comment: You did the keyboards all wrong ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156177/314301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Python 2 - 269 <s>275 290 318 337</s>

Input is mostly safe if you use triple-quotes:`"""print("Hello, World!"); sys.exit()"""`

```py
C=D=0
r=''
l,u,c=" `1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'#\\zxcvbnm,./",' \xac!"\xa3$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:@~|ZXCVBNM<>?'," `1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;'#\\ZXCVBNM,./"
for h in input():w=h!=' ';U=h in u;C^=w&U&~D;D=U&w;r+=[l,c][C][[l,u][U].find(h)]
print r
```

Encoding doesn't seem to help much, <s>except with the awkward ¬ and £ characters (I've tried looking at other problems like this and I think I should try to use split?)</s>(It doesn't seem like the keyboard compresses enough to make it worth `.decode`, etc...)

Also, spaces suck.

Edit note: Indexing is *weird*

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell - 295

Takes input from the console (Read-Host), and outputs to the console.

```
$d=@("``1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'#\zxcvbnm,./ ","``1234567890-=QWERTYUIOP[]ASDFGHJKL;'#\ZXCVBNM,./ ",'¬!"£$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:@~|ZXCVBNM<>? ')
((Read-Host).ToCharArray()|%{if($_-eq' '-or$d[2].IndexOf($_)-lt0){$a=0}else{if(!$a){$b=!$b}$a=2}$d[$b][$d[$a].IndexOf($_)]})-join''
```